# POST and GET with .NET CORE

Tags: c#, .net-core

I need to to send a request with JSON body to a POST web service. I then need to capture the result of this POST (also JSON) and use it for a body in another GET method in the web service.

I tried looking for it online and tried implementing this, but some logic is missing and I can't figure how to do it. What I'm missing is

1. how to capture the result of the web service as a Stream(or any other object for that matter) ?
2. Is line 12 ok? Can I convert a string of JSON or do I need to create a new object?

This is my code:

```
 public async Task LoadCampaignTempleteJSONAsync()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var postBody = @"{
                      ""name"":""Pages View id export 2018 - 08 - 01"",
                      ""fields"":{
                                 ""ActivityId"": ""{{Activity.Id}}"",
                                 ....
                                 }";
                     //Will it work like this, or do I need to create an object with this input ?
            string jsonInString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postBody);
            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("https://...", new StringContent(jsonInString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    // How do I capture the output of the method as a Stream for the next part?
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
        }
        Stream s; 
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(s))
        { 
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            var container = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CampaignTemplete>(json);
            string newUri = "\"syncedInstanceUri\":\"" + container.uri +"\"";
            LoadAllCampaignsJSON(newUri);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is no C code. If this is C#, please use proper tag. These are very different languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you should remove row `string jsonInString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postBody);` since `postBody` variable already has a JSON object, so you should post it like:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("https://...", new StringContent(postBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

Then, you don't need any Stream if you just want to deserialize the response, read it as string insead:

```
string data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var container = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CampaignTemplete>(data);
```

> and use it for a body in another GET method in the web service

You can't set a body for Get request.